# select element with jquery using a criteria on element child class

Tags: jquery

I have a dom like this :

```
<div class=main>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class=main>
    <div class="child b"></div> 
</div>
<div class=main>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class=main>
    <div class="child b"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to select thanks to jquery all main div element which has a child without the class "b". So I would be getting the first and the third element.
This is what I have done and it's not working, it returns me all the elements :

```
$(".main").not(".b")
```

I have also tried this, but it throws me an exception "invalid token" :

```
$(".main").not(":.b")
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use combine `:not` and `:has` selector:

```
$('.main:not(:has(".b"))');
```

or find the child element that do not have class b and then traverse to such elements parent using `.parent()` selector:

```
$('.child:not(".b")').parent()
```

Comment: Thanks, the first solution seems to be working, I am still testing it to see if it procurs any bug.

Answer (score 1):

CSS selectors can't go upside way. You can't have the parent from a child. So you can't do this with only one selector. But you can do this :

```
var elements = $('.main').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).children('.b');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('.main:not(:has(".b"))')` as posted by Milind Anantwar or you could use:

```
$('.child:not(.b)').closest('.main');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.main').find('[class=child]')` - this will give the two elements which has only child class.

`$('.main').find('[class^=child]')` - this will return all 4 child class elements

Answer (score 0):

you can also use try like this:

```
$(".main").children().not(".b");
```

As the "child" class elements are child of "main" class elements, you cannot use directly `$(".main").not(".b");` -- this will check at parent level.

Answer (score 0):

Map those precise instructions.

```
$('.main').map(function(){ if ($(this).find('div').not('.child.b').length > 0) return this; });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use directly like this.
you can get output that you want by using $.each() loop

```
 $.each($("div .main"),function(){
     if(this).not(".b")
     {
        return this;
     }
 });
```